# shell command iconv doesn't give the asked charset

Tags: character-encoding, iconv

I have a file in charset US-ASCII and want to encode it in UTF-8.

```
> file -i from.php
from.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

I type this command :

```
> sudo -u www-data iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF8 from.php > to.php
```

The file to.php is created but with the wrong charset.

```
> file -i to.php
to.php: text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

I checked the iconv list of charset and US-ASCII and UTF8 seem to be well writen.

This command doesn't work any better :

```
sudo -u www-data iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF8 -o to.php from.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

The file stay in us-ascii simply because it doesn't contain any non-ASCII characters like accented letter.

I added an accented letter in the file and retype the command :

```
> file -i to.php
to.php: text/x-php; charset=utf-8
```

Yeah !

Hope it will help someone.